# operation cannot be performed object is closed asp

Tags: asp-classic

iam executing .vbs file with calling stored procedure in it.

```
function getJobHistory(byval ServerName)

    '****************************
    '* Connecting to server

    dim rsArray

    msgbox(ServerName)

    cn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Integrated Security=SSPI"

    cmd.activeconnection =cn
    MsgBox(cn.State)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call HandleErrors(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Error Connecting To Server " & ServerName & "") 
    end if 

    'cmd.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM SYS.SYSDATABASES"
    'query1="SELECT * FROM SYS.SYSDATABASES"

    sql = "exec UMRDB..sp_Getobsoletebackupfile 0,0,0,'','','','',0,'','','',0"

    mobjwritelog.Write(query)

    'query=query & " insert into UMRDB..FileInfo select * from #fileinfo"
    'query=query & " drop table #disk drop table #file"
    'cmd.commandtext = query
    'rs.Open query,cn

    set rs=cn.Execute(sql)

    'MsgBox(rs.RecordCount) 

    do while not rs.BOF and not rs.EOF
        rsArray=rs.GetRows()
        nr=UBound(rsArray,2)
        MsgBox(nr)
        rs.MoveNext
    loop

    rs.Close

    ' end if
end function
'***********************
```

it is giving me error as following

```
Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
Code: 800A0E78
Source:  ADODB.Recordset
```

same stored procedurte is executed in query analyser.. it take 17 sec to execute procedure.what happens when i execute on .vbs script.or asp page.

Comment: -1 Tidy up the code so that it formats well and remove the commented lines.

Comment: What version of database are you using?  I had experienced a similar issue after upgrading from Sql Server 2008 to Sql Server 2010.  If the recordset was empty, it would 'close' the recordset.  I had to check the status of the recordset before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have not opened the recordset as the line containing rs.open is commented out

Edit: Actually looking closer it seems that particular line is referencing another query.  However the recordset will still need to be opened before you can use it.

Comment: i had written set rs=cn.executeSQL() this doesnt serve the purpose.. do i have to open it